# Extract values from replicate functions

Tags: r, replication, extract

I am relatively new to R and am doing a MCMC simulation using R2OpenBUGS. My model works and I trying to do multiple iterations efficiently. This is my code for the multiple iterations.

```
mcmc.s=function(n1,m1,k1,al1,be1,R.x,n2,m2,k2,al2,be2,R.y) 
{
  tq.x=replicate(n1, aa(k1,al1,be1)) #produces data
  tq.y=replicate(n2, aa(k2,al2,be2)) #produces data

  x=pfF(n1,m1,k1,tq.x) #extracts samples from data
  y=pfF(n2,m2,k2,tq.y) #extracts samples from data

  x=c(x) #Need data inputed as a list
  y=c(y) #Need data inputed as a list

  datatemp<- list( "x","y","R.x","k1","m1","R.y","k2","m2") #these are just my inputs
  aaa<-rgamma(1, shape=4.5,rate=52) #prior
  bbb<-rgamma(1, shape=4.5,rate=52) #prior
  ccc<-rgamma(1, shape=20.5,rate=3.5) #prior

  initstemp<-function(){list(a=aaa,b=bbb,c=ccc)} #assigns priors to parameters in model
  bugstemp = bugs(data=datatemp,inits=initstemp,parameters.to.save=c("a","b","c"),n.iter= 50000, model.file=mtemp,
                  n.chains=3, n.burnin=40000,n.thin=1,codaPkg =F, debug=F)
  out<-bugstemp$summary
  acalc<-out["a","mean"];bcalc<-out["b","mean"];ccalc<-out["c","mean"] #line not necessary
  return(out)
}

iter=2
out=replicate(iter,mcmc.s(n1,m1,k1,al1,be1,R.x,n2,m2,k2,al2,be2,R.y))
out
```

The results look like:

```
, , 1

                mean         sd        2.5%      25%       50%      75%      97.5%     Rhat n.eff
a         0.07904428 0.03935658  0.02335975  0.05045  0.072255  0.10020  0.1738025 1.001631  2900
b         0.03557510 0.01966588  0.00946790  0.02168  0.031765  0.04493  0.0842925 1.001946  2000
c         7.05248063 2.62808107  3.24794998  5.19200  6.603000  8.43600 13.3402499 1.001574  5600
deviance 61.80275800 2.58984760 58.86000000 59.93000 61.130000 62.98000 68.6200000 1.006417   720

, , 2

               mean         sd        2.5%     25%      50%     75%     97.5%     Rhat n.eff
a         0.1992745 0.08962024  0.06359975  0.1340  0.18575  0.2506  0.413400 1.002039  1800
b         0.1648684 0.07519227  0.05357925  0.1103  0.15280  0.2070  0.341905 1.001840  2200
c         7.2121513 1.92005357  3.90300000  5.8610  7.05700  8.4000 11.320250 1.001200  8000
deviance 47.8683650 2.54986184 44.99000000 46.0300 47.22000 48.9900 54.530000 1.001291  5800
```

Is there a way to extract the means for the parameters a,b, and c? I thought about using a for loop in the simulation function like:

```
acalc<-numeric(length=iter)
bcalc<-numeric(length=iter)
ccalc<-numeric(length=iter)
for (i in 1:iter){acalc[i]<-out["a","mean"];bcalc[i]<-out["b","mean"];ccalc[i]<-out["c","mean"]}
```

But this does not seem to work. Any ideas on how I could extract this information would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the `dput()` of your results.

Comment: @Chrisss I actually just figured out the solution to my own question. I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just solved my own question. Each value in the iteration result out can be extracted with: out[some number]. For example:

```
out[1]=0.07904428, out[2]=0.03557510, out[3]=7.05248063 , out[4]=61.80275800, out[5]=0.03935658
```

Therefore "out" is like one large vector "snaking" through all my data. Once it "snaked" through my first iteration results, it moved to my second iteration. Because each iteration will always be of the same dimension, each value I want to extract will always to 36 places away from my starting point. This realization made it possible for me to create a for-loop that would allow me to get only the values I wanted.

```
#This is for acalc
for (i in 1:length(out)){acalc[i]<-out[(i-1)*36+1]}
acalc <- as.numeric(na.omit(acalc))

#This is for bcalc
for (i in 1:length(out)){bcalc[i]<-out[(i-1)*36+2]}
bcalc <- na.omit(bcalc)

#This is for ccalc
for (i in 1:length(out)){ccalc[i]<-out[(i-1)*36+3]}
ccalc <- na.omit(ccalc)
```

The for-loop resulted in a vector that was equivalent to the length of the out result, but it was only populated with the values corresponding to parameter in each iteration. This is why I used na.omit to get rid of the NA's.

Thanks to anyone who took the time to review my question.